# How to covert image file for CachedNetworkImage in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, image, png, dio

[image]I want to show image from api via CachedNetworkImage. But don't understand what type it returns to me. and how I should convert it.

```
@override
  Future<ResponceT<String>> getProfileImage(int version) async {
    var response = await get(ApiRoutes.getImage);
    if (!response.isSuccess) return response.copy<String>();
    return ResponceT.success<String>(response.data);
  }
```

Also in postman it returns something like that =>

```
‰PNG  IHDRôxÔú pHYsšœsRGB®ÎégAMA±üa$%IDATxíÝMŒ×yðCS¤ù!…äB®fQE# ((™D @È­L. ˆZU¨ˆ›ÄöF²›U“P8ÍÂ t%S]H¶7"êô&n QBÐ° @‘@hhu1‚ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the responseType to bytes. Check get request options

if using dio

```
await Dio().get(
      'url',
      options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes),
    );
```

Or using HTTP

```
response.bodyBytes
```

Or directly use dio download

```
await Dio().download(
      'url','save_path'
    );
```